# How do I make my sidebar navigation child menus remain expanded and active on new HTTP request in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, laravel-5

I have an issue with my child menus.When I click a child menu it becomes active after http request but I want  it to remain expanded after http request(page refresh).Menu structure is below.

```
  <ul class="sidebar-navigation>
 @foreach($parent as $parent)
 <li><a href="#">{{$parent->name}}</a>
 <ul>
 @foreach($child as $child)
 @if(isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] == $child->name)
 <li class="active"> 
 @endif
 <a href="http:example.com?name=$child->name">{{$child>name)}}</a>
 </li>
 @endforeach
 </ul>
 </li>
 @endforeach 
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, and it's what i do to acheieve this effects. i use AdminLTE, you should base this code to change your code, Basic idea is judge current route if route need open sidebar then give a class 'active'
to html tag.

Html:

```
<div class="main-sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li class="treeview {{ sidebar_open(['admin.roles.*']) }}">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user-secret"></i>
        <span>角色管理</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><a href="{{ route('admin.roles.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>角色列表</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('admin.roles.create') }}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>新建角色</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

define a helper functions:

```
<?php 
if (!function_exists('sidebar_open')) {
    function sidebar_open($routes = []) {
        $currRoute = Route::currentRouteName();
        $open = false;
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            if (str_contains($route, '*')) {
                if (str_contains($currRoute, substr($route, '-1'))) {
                $open = true;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if ($currRoute === $route) {
                $open = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $open ? 'active' : '';
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,actually my problem is not making navigation active , that is already done.I want to make my collapsible nav  remain opened(expanded) after page refresh.

Comment: @KamranAli, this way is make your nav opened.because it judge current url then give it a active status